# List of abbreviations is printed twice

Tags: overleaf, acronyms

I want to print the list of abbreviations used in my master thesis. The problem is the list is printed twice in different styles. The list I want is displayed in the image but the next block of abbreviations still appears beside it and I want to delete it!

i
Any ideas?
[image: one]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nopostdot,toc,acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\loadglsentries[acronym]{myglossaries}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\gls{rf}
\gls{dt}
\gls{svm}
\gls{mlp}
\gls{auc}
\gls{nlp}
\gls{smes}
\gls{roa}
\gls{roe}
\gls{gcc}
\gls{gaap}
\gls{vif}
\gls{csr}
\gls{sm}
\gls{sn}
\gls{nlp}
\gls{sec}
\gls{lstm}
\gls{ml}
\printglossary[title={Abbreviations},type=acronym,style=long]
\end{document}
```

myglossaries.tex :

```
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{rf}{RF}{Random Forest}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{dt}{DT}{Decision Tree}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{auc}{AUC}{Area Under Curve}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{roc}{ROC}{Receiver Operating Characteristics}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{svm}{SVM}{Support Vector Machines}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{sm}{SM}{Social Media}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{sn}{SN}{Social Networks}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{roa}{ROA}{Return on Assets}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{gcc}{GCC}{Gulf Cooperation Council}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{gaap}{GAAP}{Generally Accepted Accounting Principles}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{smes}{SMEs}{Small and medium-sized enterprises}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{vif}{VIF}{Variance Inflation Factor}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{csr}{CSR}{Corporate social responsibility}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{roe}{ROE}{Return On Equity}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{mlp}{MLP}{Multi layer Perceptron}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{nlp}{NLP}{Natural Language Processing}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{xgboost}{XGBOOST}{Extreme Gradient Boosting}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{adaboost}{ADABOOST}{Adaptive boosting}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{knn}{KNN}{K Nearest Neighbor}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{lstm}{LSTM}{Long Short Term Memory}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{lm}{LM}{Loughran Mcdonald}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{sec}{SEC}{Securities and Exchange Commission}\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{ml}{ML}{Machine Learning}
```

Comment: Please provide MWE to show problem.

Comment: I added it you can find it now

Comment: `myglossaries` was still not available.

Comment: sorry, just edited it

Comment: I didn't see them twice, cause you only have one `\printglossary[title={Abbreviations},type=acronym,style=long]` command. what do you mean by `next block of abbreviations`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first "block" is consequence of *using* the acronyms for the first time in the document. The second time only the `acronym` is displayed.

The second "block" is produced by `\printglossary` normally at the end of the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nopostdot,toc,acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\loadglsentries[acronym]{myglossaries}
\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    
    \section{First time use}
    \gls{rf}
    \gls{dt}
    \gls{svm}
    \gls{mlp}
    \gls{auc}
    \gls{nlp}
    \gls{smes}
    \gls{roa}
    \gls{roe}
    \gls{gcc}
    \gls{gaap}
    \gls{vif}
    \gls{csr}
    \gls{sm}
    \gls{sn}
    \gls{nlp}
    \gls{sec}
    \gls{lstm}
    \gls{ml}
    
    \section{Second time use}
    
    \gls{rf}
    \gls{dt}
    \gls{svm}
    \gls{mlp}
    \gls{auc}
    \gls{nlp}
    \gls{smes}
    \gls{roa}
    \gls{roe}
    \gls{gcc}
    \gls{gaap}
    \gls{vif}
    \gls{csr}
    \gls{sm}
    \gls{sn}
    \gls{nlp}
    \gls{sec}
    \gls{lstm}
    \gls{ml}
        
%   \printglossary[title={Abbreviations},type=acronym,style=long]
\end{document}
```